# I need my script to include the "LastWriteTime" property on the -Whatif output

Tags: powershell, automation

I need to edit a script that I found here so that I can first see a report of the files it will delete including File name and path along with the "LastWriteTime" property so that I can analyze the output of the script for a couple of months before executing and before I configure it as a scheduled task:

I have tried playing around with the LastWriteTime object property for a while but I dont know what else to do..

Below is the code:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

$del30 = "D:\contoso_ftp\users"

$ignore = Get-Content "C:\Users\username\Documents\Scripts\ignorelist.txt"

Get-ChildItem $del30 -Recurse | 

Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } |

Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |

Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $ignore -NotMatch | 

Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line |

Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

This is what the -Whatif output looks like so far:

What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "D:\contoso_ftp\users\ftp-contosoaccount\contoso Downloads\contosofile.zip".

So.. as you can see I need to be able to get the "LastWriteTime" property in there.

Any help or pointers into articles or documentation is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

//Lennart

Comment: You can't modify the arguments that `Remove-Item` surfaces when run with `-WhatIf` - but you _could_ replace `|Remove-Item ...` with `|Get-ChildItem -Recurse |Select FullName,LastWriteTime`

Comment: Hi guys! thanks so much for your help!!!
When I did the change that Mathias told me it gives me the info that I was looking for but I would have to re-edit the code to actually execute the deletion of the files right?

Comment: hmm I wonder what happened with the other guys reply? I removed the "Get-ChildItem" part and added what he suggested but I just get the following output:

What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "" with LastWriteTime:

Im suspecting I have to edit something within those brackets?

Thanks,
//Lennart

Comment: And yes, when you are ready to commit to the deletion of the files you will have to modify the script back to just `| Remove-Item -Recurse`

Comment: Sorry, I had left out Get-Item `| Get-ChildItem -Recurse |% {Write-host "What if: Performing the operation ""Remove File"" on target ""$($_.FullName)"" with LastWriteTime: $($_.LastWriteTime) "}` (sorry for all the edits.  I will get off SO now and go back to bed...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, the output from `-WhatIf` is rather terse - "Action: Thing" - nothing more.

You can solve this in a script by separating reporting and actual removal:

```
param(
  [string]$Path = "D:\banqsoft_ftp\users",

  [datetime]$Limit = $((Get-Date).AddDays(-30)),

  [string[]]$ignore = $(Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\Scripts\ignorelist.txt"),

  [switch]$Force
)

$targetPaths = Get-ChildItem $del30 -Recurse |
  Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
  Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $ignore -NotMatch |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line

# List files that would have been affected + their timestamps
Get-ChildItem $targetPaths -Recurse -File |Select-Object FullName,LastWriteTime

if($Force){
  # If -Force was specified then we remove as well
  $targetPaths |Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
}
```

Now you can run it as:

```
PS ~> .\script.ps1
```

... to just list the files with `LastWriteTime`, and once you're confident, run it with `-Force`:

```
PS ~> .\script.ps1 -Force
```

To actually remove the files

Comment: Your suggestion works but I need to schedule a job for this script to run once a month and actually execute the deletion.

What Im trying to figure now tho is how to add the -Force parameter on the Scheduled task after I have mapped up the script?

I tried reading this article but it didnt work for me.. I think Im adding the -Force parameter in the wrong place:

This is the string that Im using under the "Add arguments (optional) field: C:\Users\userX\Documents\Scripts\DeleteFilesOlderThan30 - 01.ps1 -RunType$targetPaths -Force

Answer (score 4):

You can't modify the output of `Remove-Item` when run with `-WhatIf` but you could wrap your pipeline in a function that supports `-WhatIf` and provides its own customized `-WhatIf` output:

```
function Test-Something {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]    # This enables -WhatIf processing
    param (
        [string] $path,
        [datetime] $limit,
        [string] $ignore
    )
        
    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | 

    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } |
        
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
        
    Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $ignore -NotMatch | 
        
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line |

    Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

        # If -WhatIf is passed, output the message and skip the deletion.
        # Else enter the if-block and delete the file.
        if( $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess( 
                "Performing the operation `"Remove File`" on target `"$_`" (LastWriteTime: $($_.LastWriteTime))", 
                "Are you sure you want to delete file `"$_`" ?", 
                "Confirm" ) ) {
                
            Remove-Item $_ 
        }
    }  
}
```

Note that I didn't have to define the `-WhatIf` parameter within the function because it is added automatically by specifying `SupportsShouldProcess`. Now you can pass `-WhatIf` to your function to do a dry run:

```
Test-Something $del30 $limit $ignore -WhatIf
```

Sample output:

```text
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\test\file1.txt" (LastWriteTime: 12/30/2020 19:47:10)
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\test\file2.txt" (LastWriteTime: 01/12/2021 00:59:59)
```

---

I've used the [`$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.shouldprocess?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_Cmdlet_ShouldProcess_System_String_System_String_System_String_) that takes three arguments to provide a detailed `-WhatIf` message. The other two arguments provide a message and a headline for the related `-Confirm` argument, which is also supported by the function:

```
Test-Something $del30 $limit $ignore -Confirm
```

Now PowerShell will ask before deletion:

```text
Confirm
Are you sure you want to delete file "C:\test\file1.txt" ?
[Y] Yes [A] Yes to All [N] No [L] No to All [S] Suspend [?] Help (default is "Yes"):
```

---

Another cool feature you get for free is the verbose output. When you call the function with `-Verbose` the message supplied to `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` will be used as the verbose output:

```
Test-Something $del30 $limit $ignore -Verbose
```

Output:

```text
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\test\file1.txt" (LastWriteTime: 12/30/2020 19:47:10)
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\test\file2.txt" (LastWriteTime: 01/12/2021 00:59:59)
```

---

Further reading: [Everything you wanted to know about ShouldProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-shouldprocess?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 1):

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) notes, **you have no control over the target-object descriptions** that cmdlets use with the [common `-WhatIf` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#whatif), PowerShell's dry-run feature.

Here's a **workaround**, but note that it is *suboptimal*, mostly because use of a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call with per-object execution of a script block slows the command down noticeably:

```
'file1.txt', 'file2.txt' | # Stand-in for everything before your Remove-Item call
  Get-Item | # transform strings into [System.IO.FileInfo] objects
    ForEach-Object {
      $whatIf = $true # Set this to $false later to perform actual deletion.
      # Prepend the last-write timestamp *without a trailing newline*
      if ($whatIf) { Write-Host -NoNewline "$($_.LastWriteTime): " }
      # Let Remove-Item append its what-if message
      $_ | Remove-Item -WhatIf:$whatif
    }
```

The output will look something like this:

```
02/07/2021 15:44:24: What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "/Users/jdoe/file1.txt".
02/07/2021 15:44:24: What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "/Users/jdoe/file2.txt".
```

Note:

- If you want to **control the `-WhatIf` flag from *outside* your script**, you have two options:

  - **Either**: Decorate your script's `param(...)` block with a `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]` attribute to turn on `-WhatIf` common-parameter support:

    - **Caveat**: This will make calls to *all* cmdlets in your script that support `-WhatIf` apply it *implicitly* when you pass `-WhatIf` to your script, though you can selectively suppress that with `-WhatIf:$false`; see the alternative below for the inverse approach.
    - Since PowerShell automatically translates this common parameter into a local `$WhatIfPreference` *preference* variable, the code above must be adapted:

      - Use `if ($WhatIfPreference)` to test if `-WhatIf` was passed and `Write-Host` output should be produced.
      - *Remove* `-WhatIf:$whatIf` from the `Remove-Item` call - if `-WhatIf` is passed to your script, it will apply automatically
  - **Or:** If you want more control, use a *custom* `[switch] $WhatIf` parameter declaration *instead* of `SupportsShouldProcess`, and  query `$WhatIf` / apply `-WhatIf:$WhatIf` *explicitly and selectively*.

    - In this case, simply remove the `$whatIf = $true` statement from the code above.
    - **Caveat**: Your script will then *not* respect the `$WhatIfPreference` variable, unless you explicitly check for it in case `-WhatIf` wasn't explicitly passed (check with `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WhatIf')`).
- You can get as verbose as you like with the inline `Write-Host` call, but note that *single-line* output is only possible if you *prepend* the `Write-Host` output.

  - Alternatively, adapting [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel)'s approach from a comment on the question, you can adapt the `if` statement above to bypass the `Remove-Item -WhatIf` call altogether if `$whatIf` is set to `$true` in the script block, and craft the full what-if message yourself:

    ```
    if ($whatif) { Write-Host ...  } else { $_ | Remove-Item }
    ```
- Note that `-WhatIf` output can neither be captured nor suppressed - it always prints directly to the host (console).