# Adding -WhatIf or a 'Log Only' ability to a script?

Tags: powershell, scripting

So I've got the script below.. Many of you have helped me with over the past couple weeks. Anyway my boss wants me to add in a -whatif funtionality to this. Or some mode to run but only log the whatif parts. Anyway, I'm new to functions as a whole but from what I gather if you are using Advanced functions then your function has access to the other Powershell switches available. But how does one implement -whatif to a script that contains multiple functions? Is it as easy as adding the parameter to each function?
Here's my sanitized code:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------[Initializations]-------------------------------------------------------- 
 
#Dot Source required Function Libraries
#. "\\server\e$\scripts\Logging_Functions.ps1" 
. "c:\users\documents\powershell\Logging_Functions.ps1"

#Error Action
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
#Debug preference
$global:DebugPreference = "continue"

#----------------------------------------------------------[Declarations]----------------------------------------------------------
  
#Script Version
$sScriptVersion = "1.0"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Log File Info
$sLogPath = "C:\Users\Documents\powershell\Logs"
#$sLogPath = "\\server\e$\Logs"
$sLogName = "Set-LitmosGroups_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).log"
$sLogFile = Join-Path -Path $sLogPath -ChildPath $sLogName
$LogLine = $null 


#Variable Initializations
#Org Unit where the target groups reside (Litmos)
$OU = "ou=test_litmos, ou=test accounts, ou=domain, dc=company, dc=net"
#Org unt containing the All Managers security group
$OU2 = "CN=All Managers,OU=Organizational,OU=Groups,OU=domain,DC=company,DC=net"

# Get member of the 'ALL Managers' security group
$Managers = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $OU2 | Select-Object -expandproperty samaccountname

# Get AD groups with Report to in the name in $ou
$ReportsTo = Get-adgroup -searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" |  
Select-Object -expandproperty name

#----------------------------------------------------------[Functions]-------------------------------------------------------------

Function Get-DirectReport {
    #requires -Module ActiveDirectory
 
    <#
.SYNOPSIS
    This script will get a user's direct reports recursively from ActiveDirectory unless specified with the NoRecurse parameter.
    It also uses the user's EmployeeID attribute as a way to exclude service accounts and/or non standard accounts that are in the reporting structure.
  
.NOTES
    Name: Get-DirectReport
    Author: theSysadminChannel
    Version: 1.0
    DateCreated: 2020-Jan-28
  
.LINK
    https://thesysadminchannel.com/get-direct-reports-in-active-directory-using-powershell-recursive -  
  
.PARAMETER SamAccountName
    Specify the samaccountname (username) to see their direct reports.
  
.PARAMETER NoRecurse
    Using this option will not drill down further than one level.
  
.EXAMPLE
    Get-DirectReport username
  
.EXAMPLE
    Get-DirectReport -SamAccountName username -NoRecurse
  
.EXAMPLE
    "username" | Get-DirectReport
#>
 
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
 
        [string]  $SamAccountName,
 
        [switch]  $NoRecurse
    )
 
    BEGIN {}
 
    PROCESS {
        $UserAccount = Get-ADUser $SamAccountName -Properties DirectReports, DisplayName
        $UserAccount | select -ExpandProperty DirectReports | ForEach-Object {
            $User = Get-ADUser $_ -Properties DirectReports, DisplayName, Title, EmployeeID
            if ($null -ne $User.EmployeeID) {
                if (-not $NoRecurse) {
                    Get-DirectReport $User.SamAccountName
                }
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    SamAccountName    = $User.SamAccountName
                    UserPrincipalName = $User.UserPrincipalName
                    DisplayName       = $User.DisplayName
                    Manager           = $UserAccount.DisplayName
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    END {}
 
}

Function New-bhReportToGroup {

    [CmdletBinding()]

    $script:ReportsTo = $ReportsTo -replace ("Report to ", "")
    if ($manager -notin $ReportsTo) { 
        new-adgroup -name "Report to $manager" -groupscope global -path $ou
        #write-host "Report to $manager"
        $LogLine = "New group for " + $manager + " has been created."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
    else {
        #write-host "group for $manager already exists"
        $LogLine = "Group for " + $manager + " already exists."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
}

Function Get-bhDReports {
    [CmdletBinding()]
$script:directreports = Get-Directreport $manager -norecurse  | Select-Object samAccountName
if ($null -ne $directreports) {    
    #write-host "Got reports for $manager"    
    $LogLine = "Gathering direct reports for " + $manager
    Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
} else {
    #write-host "$manager has no reports"
    $LogLine = $manager + " has no reports."
    Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }   
}

Function Set-bhRTGmembers {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    #
    # Get manager's 'report to <manager>' group again to update members
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $Manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.Name -members $DirectReports
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.name -members $Manager
        #write-host "Report to $manager updated"
        $LogLine = "Report to " + $Manager + " updated."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
    else {
        #write-host "Couldnt find group for $manager"
        $LogLine = "Could not find group for " + $Manager
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
    }
}

Foreach ($Manager in $Managers) {
    New-bhReportToGroup
    Get-bhDReports
    Set-bhRTGmembers
   }

Foreach ($Report in $ReportsTo) {
    $report = $report -replace ("Report to ","")
     if ($Report -notin $managers) 
        {Remove-ADGroup -Identity "Report to $Report" -confirm:$false
        write-host "$report removed"
         $LogLine = $report + " user has fell out of scope, Report group removed."
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine
        } else {
        $LogLine = "No groups deleted.`n"
        Log-Write -LogPath $sLogFile -LineValue $LogLine 
}
}
```

Comment: Adding `-WhatIf` support is pretty straightforward using `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]`, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66092956/7571258) for an example.

Comment: I'm reading it through.. I think i get it but I need to re-read it another couple times. So can you tell me.. at the bottom it says that -whatIf can neither be suppressed nor captured.. it always prints to the console. So what it I needed the resulting output from -WhatIf passed to a log file?

Comment: Oh wait you chose the -Force comment as the answer.. any chance your script had multiple functions to contend with?

Comment: The "not capturable" property of common parameter `-WhatIf` is surprising. Would be interesting to know if there is a reasoning behind it or if it is just an oversight. Nevertheless you can add `-WhatIf` parameter yourself (as in the `-Force` example) and send the output wherever you want to.

Comment: There is a feature request to make it possible to capture `-WhatIf` output, which you might want to upvote (I just did): https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9870

Comment: @zett42 So the answer toy our previous question led me to complete mine. Toss that in as an answer and get some points.

Comment: I've voted to close as duplicate instead: [I need my script to include the "LastWriteTime" property on the -Whatif output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66092498/i-need-my-script-to-include-the-lastwritetime-property-on-the-whatif-output)